# How to use if statement with on *:CONNECT: mirc script

Tags: if-statement, irc, mirc

I would like to join three networks, authenticate towards nicksrv and send a message to a bot /or auto-join a few channels when I launch my IRC client. I am using mIRC 7.55.

What the client should do depends on which network it is. So I have an if statement for it but it is not working correctly.

With one server it works perfect, as soon as I add more than one I have issues. Something must be wrong with my syntax, or maybe if there is something else I could use than `$server` ?

```
on *:start: {
  /server irc.gazellegames.net:+7000
  /server -m irc.scratch-network.net:+7000
  /server -m irc.myanonamouse.net:+6697
}
on *:CONNECT: {
  if ($server = "horus.gazellegames.net" || "anubis.gazellegames.net") {
    /msg NickServ IDENTIFY password
    /msg Vertigo ENTER username password
  }
  if ($server = brooklyn.scratch-network.net) {
    /msg NickServ IDENTIFY password
    /msg Drone enter #channel1 username password
  }
  if ($server = "irc.myanonamouse.net" || "irc2.myanonamouse.net") {
    /msg NickServ IDENTIFY password
    /j #channel1,#channel2
  }
}
```

Expected result would be to join the networks and follow the IF STATEMENT and authenticate with correct credentials for each network. Script works but it is unreliable.

The script seems to send everything to first server it connects to, see snippet here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGuC4.jpg

And it is unable to join the second channel for irc.myanonamouse.net/irc2.myanonamouse.net.

I would like to avoid leaking my credentials and automate it, so I just need to launch the client to join all networks, authenticate, message a bot or join a few channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've split the different types of activities to a specific alias handler and passed it the network identifier. i.e: *SpecificNetworkCommands*, *JoinNetworkChannels*

I've also removed the NickServ authentication from the connect procedure, and will not only fire the response when triggered by NickServ initiating *ON NOTICE* event. This will helped you always be authenticated in case the Network Services restarted and are asking you to re-authenticate.

**Note:**

1. All of those repetitive `if $network ==` can be make dynamic and cleaner, by further creating a storing mechanism for `Authentications` or `AutoJoins`.
2. You can also, use Authentication\Identification, AutoJoin, Perform commands mSL scripting that will do every part of this for you without any effort and with most of the time with UI.

Code: (Not been tested)

```
ON *:CONNECT: {
  SpecificNetworkCommands $network
  JoinNetworkChannels $network
}

; This will send network credentials whenever required.
ON *:NOTICE:This nickname is registered*:?: {
  if ($nick == NickServ) {
    var %username, %password
    if ($network == NetworkName1) {
      %username = MyNetworkName1Username
      %password = MyNetworkName1Password
    }
    elseif ($network == NetworkName2) {
      %username = MyNetworkName2Username
      %password = MyNetworkName2Password
    }
    elseif ($network == freenode) {
      %username = MyFreeNodeUsername
      %password = MyFreeNodePassword
    }

    if (%username && %password) {
      msg nickserv identify %username %password
    }
  }
}

; Contain network specific actions
; $1 means the passed $network parameter
alias SpecificNetworkCommands {
  if ($1 == GGn) {
    msg Vertigo ENTER username password
  }
  elseif ($1 == Scratch-Network) {
    msg Drone enter #channel username password
  }
}

; Joining the specific network channels
; $1 means the passed $network parameter
alias JoinNetworkChannels {
  if ($1 == MYANONAMOUSE) {
    join #channel1
    join #channel2
  }
  elseif ($1 == freenode) {
    join #channel1
    join #channel2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by entering nickserv authentication on each server, tools -> options -> servers -> select server and choose edit -> login method = nickserv (/msg nickserv) -> enter your password and save.

I also swapped out `$server` to `$network` instead, seems more reliable.

```
on *:start: {
  /server irc.gazellegames.net:+7000
  /server -m irc.scratch-network.net:+7000
  /server -m irc.myanonamouse.net:+6697
}
on *:CONNECT: {

  if ($network = MYANONAMOUSE) {
    /j #channel1
    /j #channel2
  }
  if ($network = GGn) {
    /msg Vertigo ENTER username password
  }
  if ($network = Scratch-Network) {
    /msg Drone enter #channel username password
  }
}
```

Comment: I would do it differently in case of a `NickServ` authentication, if you still want to another solution, i would be happy to writ eit

Comment: I created an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use two equal signs "==" likes so:

```
on *:CONNECT: {
  if ($network == MYANONAMOUSE) {
     /join #channel1
  }
}
```

Also in your `$server` wildcard match you should use "`iswm`" like so:

```
if (*myanonamouse.net iswm $server) {
  if ($network == myanonamouse) {
    /join #channel1
  }
}
```

That is just to demonstrate `iswm` (is wild match) you don't actually need it.